# Passing objects atomically across threads without locks or data races for audio synchronization

Tags: c++, pointers, audio, lock-free, atomic

I am learning about one of the hardest parts of Audio development: the synchronization between the audio thread and the GUI thread.  Per the discussion here https://forum.juce.com/t/timur-doumler-talks-on-c-audio-sharing-data-across-threads/26311 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460829/lock-free-swap-of-two-unique-ptrt
I'm wondering if the following class solves the problem or comes close to solving it.

```
template<typename T>
struct SmartAtomicPtr
{
    SmartAtomicPtr( T* newT )
    {
        update( newT );
    }
    ~SmartAtomicPtr()
    {
        update(nullptr);
    }
    void update( T* newT, std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst ) 
    {
        keepAlive.reset( atomicTptr.exchange( newT, ord ) );
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> getShared(std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst) 
    { 
       return std::make_shared<T>( atomicTptr.load(ord) );
    }
    T* getRaw(std::memory_order ord = memory_order_seq_cst) 
    { 
         return atomicTptr.load(ord);
    }
private:
    std::atomic<T*> atomicTptr{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<T> keepAlive;
};
```

I know that whatever value ends up in the shared_ptr won't be deleted until the `SmartAtomicPtr` goes out of scope, which is fine.

the ultimate goal would be a lock-free, wait-free solution.

an example of where this might get used is the following interleaving of the audio and message thread.  The goal is to keep the returned object from dangling

```
/*
AudioProcessor owns a SmartAtomicPtr<T> ptr that the message 
thread has public access to.
*/
/* audio thread */ auto* t = ptr.getRaw();
/* message thread */ processor.ptr.update( new T() );
/* audio thread */ t->doSomething(); //t is a dangling pointer now
```

with getShared(), I believe that `t` no longer dangles:

```
/* audio thread */ auto t = ptr.getShared();
/* message thread */ processor.ptr.update( new T() );
/* audio thread */ t->doSomething(); //t is one of 2 shared_ptrs 
//holding the previous atomic value of ptr
```

I ran into some double-deletes, but I believe I have solved them, and also prevented the shared_ptr member from being stomped on in the event you call `getShared()` and `update()` at the same time, and also kept it leak-free.

any thoughts?

Comment: From C++20, there's [`std::atomic<shared_ptr<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) partial specialization.  You'll want to understand how it works if you're implementing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keepAlive.reset` is not thread safe. So your class as a whole cannot be thread safe.

Comment: Concrete proof that a short answer can be a great answer - good one!

Comment: thanks @ratchet.  I ended up using a couple FIFOs and a lot of std::move() to ensure construction and destruction happened on the gui thread, even though usage was happening on the audio thread for my project.